# how to start minikube after restart my host pc

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, podman, cri-o

I install minikube on ubuntu 22.04 with podman and cri-o ,
the issue I have the pc will be late if I restart, and minikube will not work after restart my pc. this is my status after restart

```
$ minikube status 
E0627 11:54:21.381414   22556 status.go:261] The "minikube" host does not exist!
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Nonexistent
kubelet: Nonexistent
apiserver: Nonexistent
kubeconfig: Nonexistent
```

So how to handle my cluster before and after restart the pc

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```bash
# Delete existing cluster
minikube delete

# Start new cluster
minikube start
```

Comment: I think this will delete all the apps and deployments and settings...

Comment: Of course, it will cant you deploy them again? minikube is a development cluster